# Running code when flatlist has a new item in React Native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native so this may be a stupid question. I have created an app this displays I list of podcast in a flatlist which are picked up from a json file. I am using onesignal within my app to display notifications. I would like to display a notification each time a new podcast has been added to the flatlist.

I am unsure if I should check if the setstate has been updated or if the flatlist has been updated.

Here is my flatlist code

```js
export default class MainScreen extends React.Component 
{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: true
    }
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    fetch('http://85356914f79f.ngrok.io/backend/FilterCat.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
   
        // Getting the id.
        id: this.props.navigation.state.params.FlatListClickItemHolder
    })

   }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        dataSource: responseJson,
        
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
  FlatListViewItemSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
      style={{
        height: .5,
        width: "100%",
        backgroundColor: "#000",
      }}
    />
    );
  }

  OpenSecondActivity(id) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate("Podcast", { FlatListClickItemHolder: id});
  }


  render() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
          <ActivityIndicator />
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={styles.MainContainer}>
        <FlatList style={{paddingTop: 30}}
          data={ this.state.dataSource }
          ItemSeparatorComponent = {this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={this._renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
     
     _renderItem = ({item}) => {

      return(
          <View style={styles.MainView}>
            <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
              <Text style={styles.rowViewContainer} onPress={this.OpenSecondActivity.bind(this, item.id)}>{item.Name}</Text>
              {/* <Text style={styles.Text}>{item.By}</Text> */}
              <Text style={styles.Text}> - {item.DateRecorded}</Text>
          </View>
          </View>
      );
    }
    
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need a different approach. Flatlist won't be involved at all with the solution.

It's very likely the user won't have the app open when a new podcast is released, so you'll need to figure out a way to send a notification despite any state of the app.

What backend are you using? Where do your podcasts come from? This is where your flow will start.

You'll need to create a listener on your database the listens for changes to your podcasts list. This will trigger a notification that needs to be sent to the user.

Here's Onesignal's [documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/data-notifications) about this feature. It is called **Push Notification**. Usually you set up a service on your app that receives these notifications even while the app is terminated.

Comment: I am using php and mysql to store and receive the podcast and I am using node with express to run my notifications